# accidentally sent ETC to ETH

Tags: ethereum-classic, coinbase

pls help I accidentally mistakenly sent ETC to ETH, and I have been reached out to my coinbase and third party and they said they didn't receive it and it showed the transaction details and lost the funds. I'm desperate and freaking out about my funds.

Comment: You should always do a test transaction first. Anyway, no point in me saying that now since it already happened. To clarify, you sent your ETC to an Ethereum address? Is that Ethereum address controlled by you or a third party? If it's a third party, who?

Comment: Transaction hash would help. Also, if the owner of the `to` address is not willing to send it back to you... well, too bad.

Comment: It was online gaming and I sent my ETC to Ethereum , they are a third party

Comment: Can anyone help? Pls

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing you can do, only the owner of the recipient address is able to access those funds. Both ETH and ETC use the same kind of private key, if they have the private key they could access those funds using an ETC wallet. If the recipient is a contract it is more complex and expensive. Some online wallets don't support recovering funds because it could be too complex, or charge a fee for the manual processing.